# Regex missing to capture last key-value list entry

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string such as this one:

```
a=func(1, 2, 2), b='hey', c=foobar('text'), d=1
```

which I'd like to parse into its key-value components, so that I can obtain a list of

```
[['a', 'func(1, 2, 2)', ['b', '\'hey\''], ['c', 'foobar(\'text\')'], ['d', '1']]
```

My approach was to use this regex: `(\w*) *= *([^=]*), (?=\w* *=)` with a positive lookahead, but that's ignoring the last key-value pair (`d=1`). Any idea how I can make the positive lookahead optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the regex pattern `(\w+)=(.*?)(?:,\s*(?=\w+=)|$)`, and then capture all matches:

```js
var input = "a=func(1, 2, 2), b='hey', c=foobar('text'), d=1";
var regex = /(\w+)=(.*?)(?:,\s*(?=\w+=)|$)/g;
var match = regex.exec(input);
var result = [];
while (match != null) {
    result.push(new Array(match[1], match[2]));
    match = regex.exec(input);
}
console.log(result);
```

Here is what the pattern does:

```
(\w+)               match AND capture a key
=                   match an =
(.*?)               then match AND capture anything, until we see
(?:,\s*(?=\w+=)|$)  a comma, followed by optional space, and the next key
                    OR the end of the input string
```

Then, we build your expected 2D array using the first capture group as the key, and the second capture group as the value.

Comment: Thanks. What is `?:` doing?

Comment: @orange Please read [What does ?: do in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705842/what-does-do-in-regex).  `?:` turns off the capture group for that term, because we aren't interested in capturing it (we only care about the LHS and RHS of the variable assignments).

Comment: Wouldn't that mean we don't really need the `?=`?

Comment: `(?=\w+=)` is a positive lookahead.  `?=` does _not_ mean a question mark followed by `=`.  Read about lookarounds in regex.

Comment: If you define `(?:,\s*(?=\w+=)|$)` as a non-matching group, isn't the positive lookahead redundant (a non-matching group is kind of the same, that is _optional_)? (Btw, the positive lookahead was part of my initial suggestion...)

Comment: No.  The group is part of the pattern regardless of whether `?:` appears or not.