# Java regex parsing out middle value of String

Tags: java, regex

I have some data that comes in as a String, and I need to extract or print out the **monthvalue** ( middle group) that is in the form:

**[itemvalue] [monthvalue] [yearvalue]**

*The rules are:*

**itemvalue** = can be 1-3 characters (or digits) in length

**monthvalue** = is single alpha character [a-z]

**yearvalue** = can be 1, 2, or 4 digits representing calender year

Some Example Inputs:

**Input1**

`AP18`

**Output1**

`P`

**Input2**

`QZAB19`

**Output2**

`B`

**Input3**

`ARM8`

**Output3**

`M`

I was trying to **compile** a **pattern** like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3})([a-z])([0-9]{1,4})");
```

and then call **matcher** on the input to **find()** the groups, in this case, the **monthvalue**, which should be **matcher.group(2)** like:

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("OneOfTheExampleInputStringsFromAbove"); 

    if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

I thought I was close but one issue was how to include a length of 1, 2 and 4, but exclude 3 length for the **yearvalue**. Is my approach good? Am I missing anything in my Compile pattern?

please let me know!

Comment: Q: Will every item code always include all three parts: itemValue, monthValue and yearValue?  Q: What's the rule for determining how long itemValue is: whether it's one, two or three characters?

Comment: Yes, each input will have three parts. There is no rule for determining itemvalue length, it can just be 1 to 3 characters or digits at random. That's why I thought regex was the best approach.

Comment: You can use or condition to exclude length 3.

Comment: @ennth; if any of the below answer helps; please accept the one which best suits you and close this post. It'll help the answerer as well as the future readers of this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is correct. To add your last requirement you may try:

```
^\w{1,3}([a-zA-Z])(?:\d{1,2}|\d{4})$
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    This part
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of line respectively.
>
> **`\w{1,3}`** - Matches from `[0-9A-Za-z_]` 1 to 3 times. If there is a chance that your test string contains **`_`**; then try to use `[0-9A-Za-z]` here.
>
> **`([a-zA-Z])`** - Represents capturing group matching a letter.
>
> **`(?:\d{1,2}|\d{4})`** - Represents a non-capturing group matching the digits 1, 2 or 4 times **but not three**.

You can find the above regex demo in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/wzf6Gm/4)

[image: pictorial Representation]

**Implementation in java:**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class Main
{
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w{1,3}([a-zA-Z])(?:\\d{1,2}|\\d{4})$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String string = "QZAB19\n"
     + "AP18\n"
     + "ARM8\n"
     + "ARM803"; // This won't match since the year value is 3.
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
     while(matcher.find())System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // 1st group matches the month-value.
    }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/SklMYSj2I)

Comment: but would''t \d {1,4} on the yearvalue pick up a length of 3? that violates the yearvalue rule.

Comment: Updated the regex.Please check

Answer (score 1):

If you looking something different than a regex solution then the below could help:

```
String txt = "QZAB19";
String month = txt.replaceAll("[0-9]", ""); //replaces all integers
System.out.println(month.charAt(month.length()-1)); //get you the last character that is month
```

**Output:**

```
B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3})([a-zA-Z])(([0-9]{1,2})|([0-9]{4}))$");
```

You should use $ to restrict the end matching point else your condition for restricting digts at end of string doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, okay, this is what I was getting to also. What exactly do you mean by putting the $ at the end? And everytime I see people put the $ at the end, they also use ^ at the front, how is this different from not using ^...$  if I may ask? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you have to use ^ also to strict the start matching point. I am suggesting this because I can see that you are trying to match the whole input string, but if you want to just pick the matching part from a large string or file then you don't need to use ^ and $.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
([\w]{1,3})(\D)([\d]{1,4})
```

Examples:

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

```
Input     Match:
-----     -----
AP18      (A)(P)(18)
QZAB19    (QZA)(B)(19)
ARM8      (AR)(M)(8)
QZAB123   (QZA)(B)(123)
QZAB1234  (QZA)(B)(1234)
A123      No match
1234      No match
```

Comment: but would''t \d {1,4} on the yearvalue pick up a length of 3? that violates the yearvalue rule.

Comment: The regex will do it's job - it'll extract the values just fine. If you also want validate potentially bad input... then I'd recommend doing checking for *all* possible errors in Java, after you've extracted the values.  If you *really* want to exclude "3", [mandy8055](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255317/3135317) showed you how to combine "or" with a ["non-capture subpattern"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705842/).  Please consider "upvoting" and "accepting" his (most excellent!) reply.